# Dynamics of solutions close to $x(0)$ of $\dot{x}=\sqrt{x}+f(t)$ for $f(t)$ small when $t \ll 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I was looking at the dynamics of the real solutions close to $x(0)=0$ for the non-autonomous ODE

\begin{equation}
\dot{x}= \sqrt{x} +f(t)
\end{equation}

where $f(t)>0$ is `small' for $t \ll 1$ (in the ODE $t$ is the independent variable). Especially the possible non-uniqueness of solutions seems interesting. I am guessing that these type of equations have a name, but I was not able to find it. Does anybody know more about these type of functions.

Remark: After some transformation you can actually rewrite the ODE in the form
$(\dot{y}-1)y=f(t)$. These type of equations must have some name...

(Note that for the uniqueness theorem for first order ODEs you need smoothness (or lipschitzness) of the right hand-side w.r.t. $x$ which here clearly is not the case)

Comment: Did you mean first-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation with a forcing function?

Comment: yup, the $f(t)$ is purely dependent on $t$, but I am assuming that $f(t)$ is small for small $t$. Hence I prefer to think of it as a perturbation. But I will change the title a bit.

Comment: I'm unsure what you are looking for, so I don't know if this is of any interest. You don't have uniqueness of solutions if $f\equiv 0$, $x(0)=0$. For any $t_0\geq 0$, $$x(t)=\left\{\begin{array} (((t-t_0)/2)^2\text{ if } t\geq 0\\0\text{ if } x<0\end{array}\right.$$ is a solution.